# call func in parent UIViewController from last modal UINavigatonController UIViewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

i present a model UINavigationController like so

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let firstViewController = FirstViewController(collectionViewLayout:flowLayout)
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

this NavigationController will contain two UIViewcontrollers, 
in the last one, when I dismiss the NavigationController, i want to call a function in my main controller before dismissing

I know how to this using protocols and delegates, but only if i use just two UIViewController not a UIViewController and a UINavigationController.

like so

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func someFunction()
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

    @objc func myRightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!)
    {

        self.delegate?.someFunction()
    }
}
```

do I have to create a CustomNavigationController, or is there any other way like passing the delegate through all ViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like:

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let firstViewController = FirstViewController(collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
firstViewController.delegate = self
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or using callback instead of delegate:

```
class FViewController: UIViewController {
    var onButtonAction: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction onButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
      onButtonAction?()
    }
}

class SViewController: UIViewController {

    func someMethod() {
      let fVC = FViewController()
      fVC.onButtonAction = {}
      let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: fVC)
      present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```